# Using Async-IO of servlet3.1 with Spring

Tags: java, spring, nio, spring-web, servlet-3.1

**How to use `Async-IO`(setWriteListener) of `Servlet3.1` with Spring-5 ?**

Also, I found [Link-A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828355/is-servlet-3-1-readwritelistener-supported-by-deferredresult-in-spring-4) which mentions one needs to add Listener to outputStream.
On other hand [Link-B](https://dzone.com/articles/servlet-31spring-mvc-non-blocking-io) says it should work with `spring 5` and `tomcat 8.5+`.

Next I profiled a JVM and found that `CoyoteOutputStream.checkNonBlockingWrite` always return `false` with both `deferredResult` and `NON-DeferredResult` sample code.

```
 //MY TEST CODE  
 @GetMapping("/health")
    public DeferredResult<DummyDTO> upNRuning(){        
        DeferredResult<DummyDTO> defferedResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        newCachedThreadPool.submit(() ->
            defferedResult.setResult(new DummyDTO()));
        return defferedResult;  
    }
```

I was not able to try `Link-A` recommandation as i am not sure of `NioReadListener` implementation and its arguments.

---

PS:
Environment Spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE + Windows